# IDEA сплошное подчеркивание серым - что это?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Что означает такое вот подчеркивание?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По поводу вашей правки: нет, не «могут изменяться», а именно что изменяются. В показанном вами коде `requestLocale` тоже «может изменяться», но не подчёркивается, потому что не изменяется

Comment: Я имел в виду, если `if`-ы не сработают, то `locale` не изменится, т.е. именно МОГУТ изменяться, а не изменяются

Comment: Ваша интерпретация интересена, но, подозреваю, для анализатора кода не применима: с его точки зрения, если есть `locale =` — значит считаем за изменение, даже если завернуть в `if (false)` и реального изменения никогда не произойдёт — всё равно подчеркнётся (я не проверял, но подозреваю, что так и будет, проверьте на всякий случай)

Comment: В дубликате неверный ответ. Тут правильный!

Comment: @andreymal может самому написать ответ? И там есть второй ответ, он разве тоже неправильный?

Comment: @andreymal изменил второй ответ, теперь все правильно.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IDEA таким образом выделяет переменные, значения которых могут изменяться после присвоения.

Это поведение можно настроить через **File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults | Identifiers | Reassigned local variable**